# Destroy component of aura.component type

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, html

I am creating component dynamically with cmp calling it like :

```
<parent component>
//Child Component dynamic creation
    <aura:attribute type="Aura.Component[]" name="fAttr" />
            {! v.fAttr}
</parent component>
```

and in the js creating the instance to :

```
$A.createComponent(
            'c:Footer', {
             "aura:id": "fCrt",
             isVFPage: "True",
            },
            function(newButton, status, errorMessage){
                //Add the new button to the body array
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    var firstPanel = cmp.get("v.fAttr");

                    newButton.set("v.saveFunction", cmp.mymethod); 
                    firstPanel.push(newButton);
                    cmp.set("v.footerAttr", firstPanel);
                }
```

As everytime on button click the instance is creating a new component , I need to destroy it else it will create new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework automatically destroys the old instance once unset from the attribute. There is no need to take additional action.

```
cmp.set("v.fAttr", [newButton]);
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm) states you only need to manually destroy components if you never assign them to an attribute of the type `Aura.Component[]`.

> After a component that is declared in markup is no longer in use, the framework automatically destroys it and frees up its memory.
>
> If you create a component dynamically in JavaScript and that component isn't added to a facet (v.body or another attribute of type `Aura.Component[]`), you have to destroy it manually using Component.destroy() to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: Right now when somebody moves back to the main parent component and click the button again it create another without destroying the previous one causing another button at a time. I cannot even have the Ids to destroy it . Is there any way like cmp.set("v.fAttr",  to destroy and create new one ?

Comment: @sfdc-neta your code is adding the new button to an stay of the old buttons. Instead, remove the old button entirely. My code is a demonstration of this.